# How to move backgroung with repeating-linear-gradient()

Tags: css, css-tables, linear-gradients

It's a bit complicated for me to explain this by words, so please look at

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table>tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #00000062;
  width: 47px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
}

#t1 td.locked {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, #00000035 7px, #00000035 14px);
}


/**
 *  I have no success with this   
 */

#t1 td.locked:nth-child(odd) {
  background-position-y: 0px;
}

#t2 td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
}

#t2 td.locked {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-49deg, transparent, transparent 9px, #00000035 9px, #00000035 18px);
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td class="locked">1.2</td>
      <td class="locked">1.3</td>
      <td class="locked">1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td class="locked">2.2</td>
      <td class="locked">2.3</td>
      <td class="locked">2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td class="locked">3.2</td>
      <td class="locked">3.3</td>
      <td class="locked">3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td class="locked">4.2</td>
      <td class="locked">4.3</td>
      <td class="locked">4.4</td>
      <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.1</td>
      <td class="locked">5.2</td>
      <td class="locked">5.3</td>
      <td class="locked">5.4</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>



<table id="t2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td class="locked">1.2</td>
      <td class="locked">1.3</td>
      <td class="locked">1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td class="locked">2.2</td>
      <td class="locked">2.3</td>
      <td class="locked">2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td class="locked">3.2</td>
      <td class="locked">3.3</td>
      <td class="locked">3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td class="locked">4.2</td>
      <td class="locked">4.3</td>
      <td class="locked">4.4</td>
      <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.1</td>
      <td class="locked">5.2</td>
      <td class="locked">5.3</td>
      <td class="locked">5.4</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are two tables with some cells having striped background.

Striped cells in `#t2` are nearly what I want: stripes in neighboring cells almost coincide and look like that they are drawn across the whole column (or several columns).

But I don't like how I've achieved this: by adjusting cells size and stripes width and angle.

Is it possible to achieve similar look for `#t1` table by somehow "move" striped background? And don't change stripes width and angle and cells size also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may apply the gradient to the whole table instead and apply white background to the cell where you don't need the gradient.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, #00000035 7px, #00000035 14px);
}

table>tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #00000062;
  width: 47px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:not(.locked) {
  background:#fff;
}
#t2 td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td class="locked">1.2</td>
      <td class="locked">1.3</td>
      <td class="locked">1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td class="locked">2.2</td>
      <td class="locked">2.3</td>
      <td class="locked">2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td class="locked">3.2</td>
      <td class="locked">3.3</td>
      <td class="locked">3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td class="locked">4.2</td>
      <td class="locked">4.3</td>
      <td class="locked">4.4</td>
      <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.1</td>
      <td class="locked">5.2</td>
      <td class="locked">5.3</td>
      <td class="locked">5.4</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>



<table id="t2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td class="locked">1.2</td>
      <td class="locked">1.3</td>
      <td class="locked">1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td class="locked">2.2</td>
      <td class="locked">2.3</td>
      <td class="locked">2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td class="locked">3.2</td>
      <td class="locked">3.3</td>
      <td class="locked">3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td class="locked">4.2</td>
      <td class="locked">4.3</td>
      <td class="locked">4.4</td>
      <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.1</td>
      <td class="locked">5.2</td>
      <td class="locked">5.3</td>
      <td class="locked">5.4</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a common point of reference for the background.

The style needed for this is

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table>tbody td {
  border: solid 1px #00000062;
  width: 47px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
}

#t1 td.locked {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 7px, #00000035 7px, #00000035 14px);
  background-attachment: fixed; /* added */
}
```

```html
<table id="t1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td class="locked">1.2</td>
      <td class="locked">1.3</td>
      <td class="locked">1.4</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td class="locked">2.2</td>
      <td class="locked">2.3</td>
      <td class="locked">2.4</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3.1</td>
      <td class="locked">3.2</td>
      <td class="locked">3.3</td>
      <td class="locked">3.4</td>
      <td>3.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4.1</td>
      <td class="locked">4.2</td>
      <td class="locked">4.3</td>
      <td class="locked">4.4</td>
      <td>4.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5.1</td>
      <td class="locked">5.2</td>
      <td class="locked">5.3</td>
      <td class="locked">5.4</td>
      <td>5.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
```